# Removing certain parts of modelsummary in R at specific statistics

Tags: r, modelsummary

I am using `gamm4:gamm4` to model longitudinal change.

I am trying to use the `modelsummary::modelsummary` function to create an output table of the following results:

I would like to add `t-values` and `std.error` to the output of the `fixed effects`, and remove the empty tags values from the `random effects`

```
model_lmer <- gamm4(Y ~ Tract + s(Age, by = Tract, k = 10) + Sex,
            data = (DF1),
            random = ~ (0 + Tract | ID))


modelsummary(model_lmer$mer,   
             statistic = c("s.e. = {std.error}", 
                           "t = {statistic}"))
```

But I am struggling to write the correct syntax to remove the "t" and "s.e." from the random effects output.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of tricky, actually. The issue is that `modelsummary()`
automatically drops empty rows when they are filled with `NA` or an
empty string `""`. However, since `glue` strings can include arbitrary
text, it is hard to think of a *general* way to figure out if the row is
empty or not, because `modelsummary()` cannot know *ex ante* what
constitutes an empty string.

If you have an idea on how this check could be implemented, please report it
on Github:

https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary

In the meantime, you could use the powerful [`tidy_custom.CLASSNAME`
mechanism](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#adding-new-information-to-existing-models)
to customize the `statistic` and `p.value` statistics directly instead
of through a `glue` string:

```r
library(gamm4)
library(modelsummary)

# simulate
x <- runif(100)
fac <- sample(1:20,100,replace=TRUE)
eta <- x^2*3 + fac/20; fac <- as.factor(fac)
y <- rpois(100,exp(eta))

# fit
mod <- gamm4(y~s(x),family=poisson,random=~(1|fac))

# customize
tidy_custom.glmerMod <- function(x) {
    out <- parameters::parameters(x)
    out <- insight::standardize_names(out, style = "broom")
    out$statistic <- sprintf("t = %.3f", out$statistic)
    out$p.value <- sprintf("p = %.3f", out$p.value)
    out
}


# summarize
modelsummary(mod$mer,
             statistic = c("{statistic}", "{p.value}"))
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| X(Intercept) | 1.550 |
|  | t = 17.647 |
|  | p = 0.000 |
| Xs(x)Fx1 | 0.855 |
|  | t = 4.445 |
|  | p = 0.000 |
| Num.Obs. | 100 |
| RMSE | 2.49 |

Note that I used simple glue strings in `statistic = "{p.value}"`, otherwise they would be wrapped up in parentheses, as is default for standard errors.